# De Rham cohomology of $T^n$ using Künneth formula and Chevalley-Eilenberg theorem.

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

I want to calculate $H^*(T^n)$ with ring structure using both of these methods. Künneth formula gives
$$
H^p(T^n)=H^p(S^1\times T^{n-1})=\bigoplus_{i+j=p}H^i(S^1)\otimes H^j(T^{n-1})
$$
for each $p$,but $H^j(S^1)$ is only nonzero for $j=0$ and $j=1$, so I get
$$
H^p(T^n)=\mathbb{R}\otimes H^p(T^{n-1})\oplus \mathbb{R}\otimes H^{p-1}(T^{n-1})
$$
From now, it should be more or less clear that proceeding by induction I am just going to get $\mathbb{R}^{\binom{n}{p}}$, but how do I obtain the ring structure for that? 
Using Chevalley-Eilenberg, I know that
$$
H^*(K_{T^n})\cong H^*(T^n),
$$
but I don't know how to actually get the Lie algebra cohomology. How do I proceed in both cases and show that I get isomorphic answers?

Comment: The natural map that the Kunneth formula tells you is an isomorphism respects the cup product: said another way, over a field the Kunneth formula tells you that $H^{\bullet}(X \times Y)$ is the tensor product $H^{\bullet}(X) \otimes H^{\bullet}(Y)$ (of graded commutative rings).

Comment: And the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex has vanishing differential for abelian Lie algebras. You just get an exterior algebra, which is the same thing that the Kunneth formula gives you.

Comment: How do I write $H^*(T^n)$ as a quotient of a polynomial ring? Will it be $\mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ and we quotient out by the ideal generated by commutators $[x_i, x_j]$?

Comment: It is not a quotient of a polynomial ring (which is already commutative, so all the commutators are already zero). It is the exterior algebra on $n$ generators (everything is graded commutative, not commutative).